# How can i disconnect the teeth of muy 3d model from the rest of the rigged body

Tags: rigging

I'm trying to move muy model's arm but the structure inside his head  is still following that move, i also tried to chance the body's rig to sepárate it but it simply doesnt work.

Comment: Your problem is the wheights are wrong in your model. Select all verts of the teeth and remove them from all vertex groups (you can do it, if you click on the little triangle near the vertex groups), then reassign them to the correct bones. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/properties/vertex_groups/assigning_vertex_group.html

Comment: How do i select them?

Comment: i just checked the vertex groups after rigging it again and i saw that all bones i created were each one at a vertex group but i still cant find the group were the teeth are

Comment: You don't have to find the vertex group, just select all the teeth's verts then click on the little triangle, and select "Remove from All Groups"

Comment: how can i select them if i cant see them? i mean i cant see them because i have the rest of the  head around it, do i have to make the rest transparent or something? (sorry for asking somuch butim a beginner)

Comment: No problem. Select a vert on the head and hit CTRL+L. This will select the whole linked mesh, then hit H. This will hide the selected verts, so you will what is inside. You can unhide everything by hittng ALT+H.

Comment: thank you so much for the help but now i have a last issue that is driving me mad.you see